# Making arrays of columns (or rows) of a (space-delimited) textfile in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, text-files, csv

I have seen similar questions but the answers always give strings of rows. I want to make arrays of the columns of a text file. I have a textfile like this (There is a text FILE that looks like this, but has 106 rows and 19 columns):

```
O2     CO2     NOx     Ash     Other
20.9     1.6     0.04     0.0002    0.0
22.0     2.3     0.31     0.0005    0.0    
19.86     2.1     0.05     0.0002    0.0
17.06     3.01     0.28     0.006    0.001
```

I expect to have arrays of columns (either a 2D array of all columns or a 1D array of each column), and the first row is only for names so then a list for the first row. Since I would like to plot them later.

The desired result would be for example for a column:

```
   array([0.04,
         0.31 ,
         0.05,
         0.28 ], dtype=float32)
```

and for the first row:

```
   species= ['O2','CO2','NOx','Ash',' Other']
```

Comment: The delimiter is 5 spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend not to manually loop over values in large data sets (in this case a sort of tab separated relational model). Just use the methods of a safe and well-known library like NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.transpose(np.loadtxt("/path/to/file.txt", skiprows=1, delimiter="\t"))
```

with the inner `loadtxt` you read your file and with `skiprows=1` parameter skip the first row (the column names) to avoid incompatible data types and further conversions. If you need this row in the same structure just use insert a new row at index 0. then you need to transpose the matrix for which there's a safe method in NumPy as well. I just used the output of `loadtxt` (which is a list of lists for each row) as input of `transpose` to give a one-liner. But it's better to use them apart in order to avoid "train wrecks" and also be able to see what happens in between and eventually correct the unwanted results.

PS: the `delimiter` parameter must be adjusted to match the one in the original file. Check the [loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) documentation for more info. I considered it to be a TAB. @KostasCharitidis - thanks for your note

Comment: A good example, though the delimiter should be " " (a space) i think.

Comment: well, it could be anything. I see more than one space in the example and consider it as tab which is common in such files… but of course the correct delimiter should be used. I'll add the note to the answer. Thanks @KostasCharitidis

Comment: I called it tab-delimited, because I didn't know what to call the file when each are separated with 5 spaces.

Comment: tab could also be 4 spaces. 5 spaces might be tricky, there's no fix standard for that. try various regex values to omit spaces.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE3

```
st = open('file.txt', 'r').read()

dct = []
species = []

for row in st.split('\n')[0].split(' '):
    species.append(row)


for no, row in enumerate(st.split('\n')[1:]):
    dct.append([])
    for elem in row.split(' '):
        dct[no].append([float(elem)])

print(species)
print(dct)
```

RESULT

```
['O2', 'CO2', 'NOx', 'Ash', 'Other']
[[[20.9], [1.6], [0.04], [0.0002], [0.0]], [[22.0], [2.3], [0.31], [0.0005], [0.0]], [[19.86], [2.1], [0.05], [0.0002], [0.0]], [[17.06], [3.01], [0.28], [0.006], [0.001]]]
```

file.txt

```
O2 CO2 NOx Ash Other
20.9 1.6 0.04 0.0002 0.0
22.0 2.3 0.31 0.0005 0.0
19.86 2.1 0.05 0.0002 0.0
17.06 3.01 0.28 0.006 0.001
```

Comment: I get the error "'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: @Travis_h Did you run the above script? Give me a few more info or your code to help you!

Comment: I have a text file, so I read the text file as f=open('/directory/name_of_file.out' , 'r'), and then used your code and replaced with "st" with "f".

Comment: What I need are arrays of rows and columns and not a dictionary. Then I cannot still have arrays but lists of every row or columns and not arrays.

Comment: I updated it so it read from a .txt. It works fine but you need to make sure that the new lines and spaces are like this. I cannot see your text file to help you more with the regex. Also added a version with lists instead of dictionary.

Comment: Could you please write the script to make arrays and not strings or lists of every columns with '' around every number.

Comment: `[['O2', 'CO2', 'NOx', 'Ash', 'Other'], ['20.9', '1.6', '0.04', '0.0002', '0.0'], ['22.0', '2.3', '0.31', '0.0005', '0.0'], ['19.86', '2.1', '0.05', '0.0002', '0.0'], ['17.06', '3.01', '0.28', '0.006', '0.001']]` thats the result of the last example. What would be your desired result?

Comment: I added the desired result to the question.

Comment: Please put only the answer that makes the desired result and not the rest with dictionary and such if they aren't to be used for this end. It would confuse the reader, thanks.

Comment: The results look good, but when I implement your code i get the error: could not convert string to float: . Also how do I make strings of every column?

Comment: @Travis_h getting that error means that there are data in your text file that are not numbers, so you maybe need to skip the `float()` parsing and leave them as they be (strings).

Comment: In this case, then if I choose dct[2], it gives me a list also with the spaces between the numbers as array elements as well. I would like to have arrays of columns and one list of the first row.

Comment: Oh you need 2 lists then. I didn't get that in the first place. I update it again then

Comment: I need one list (of the names of species) and one array for each of the columns (without the first element, which is the name os that species)

Comment: I edited the aim array to make it more simple to make and manipulate, but still haven't been successful, also with the answers.

Comment: Did you see the update and results? Isn't that the desired? There is a list with the species (the first row) and another one with the values

Comment: No Kostas, the dct is empty and the species shows wrong list.